# Can I run a Jekyll website without a web server?

Tags: filesystems, jekyll

As per the title, can I run a Jekyll website from the file system, without a web server? i.e. on the `file:///` URL scheme.

I don't have the facility right now to build a test site to check. To my knowledge, it's basically a question of how Jekyll builds the links between the pages.

For context, my intended use case is developing a mobile app that will run web pages in a native wrapper. I've used phonegap in the past but this is something a little different, simpler. What I'm interested in is the ability to generate the pages using markdown.

Comment: Do you also have a Ruby interpreter?

Comment: Hi... i am looking for a solution for similar problem here --- > http://stackoverflow.com/q/26778329/1731150   ... were you able to find any good solution to this ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Assuming you have Ruby installed (if you're on a Mac, it comes default) you can [build a Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/usage/) project and it just spits out flat HTML files. You'd be fine working on the `file://` protocol or setting up a virtual host and using `http://`.

Up to you!