# Running jekyll generated files without jekyll / local server?

Tags: html, ruby, jekyll

I have just started working with Jekyll. As a front-end developer i have to create a lot of static pages for web applications before they go into development.

I am trying to run jekyll generated files inside the `_site` folder without a server as sometime as part of my workflow i have to send plain static HTML files to other dev team or show to clients during a presentation *(sometimes as a zip folder so can't hardcode any specific path in config file)*.

I am not able to run jekyll files from a local folder like `file:///C:/Users/` as all the links and assets only work while running from a jekyll server.

Is there any way that this can be achieved.

Thanks

Comment: Something like this perhaps: https://jclement.ca/2013/12/06/relative_jekyll_paths.html ?

Comment: This looks like it might work will test it and revert back. Just one query how do i run that ruby plugin ? or do i just have to place it in root directory ? Thanks

Comment: Place it in a `_plugins` directory (which you may need to create). You will probably need to fiddle with your pages and layouts etc. to get it all working properly but I think it’s possible.

Comment: thanks i'll try it. I don't have knowledge of ruby so didn't have any idea about this

Answer (score 17):

You can view a built Jekyll site without a server - but it needs an extra tool.

Serve your Jekyll site as normal, and use wget to clone your served site in flat format. This will work on a linux system:

- Serve the Jekyll site
- Open a new terminal, create & move into a target directory
- Run wget from this directory
- Send the resulting directory to your client

You may need to play about with wget settings, but if your site is served on port 4000 you could try something like this:

```
wget --convert-links -r http://127.0.0.1:4000/
```

You'll probably need to be careful with the recursive flag. See http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/

Comment: On Mac OS, you will need to install wget. This can be done with Homebrew: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/wget or this method using Xcode or command line tools: https://osxdaily.com/2012/05/22/install-wget-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 9):

This is fundamentally impossible with Jekyll, because the index page is a different hierarchy (/index) and each blog post is a nested URL (/posts/about). So the URLs for things like CSS and Javascript will have to be different for each page. For a post it should be "../css/..." and for index it should be "./css/". That is not possible without a running server.

So here are some options for you:

- Pass "." as the base url. So your styles will become './css/'. Now your index page will work fine, but blog posts won't (they need '../')

  ```
  jekyll serve --baseurl .
  ```
- Pass the current folder as base URL. Now you don't need a server, but your _site folder is tied to your machine's folder, and not exactly portable.

  ```
  jekyll serve --baseurl $(pwd)
  ```
- Use a lightweight server. This will start a simple server on the current folder (so make sure you go into _site folder), so you don't need jekyll to be installed. This is available by default in python, so you don't have to install anything separate, as long as python is installed.

  ```
  python -m SimpleHTTPServer <port>
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the input.. you have mentioned some good points but the whole point of this question is to run without server i have used python server & it works fine but i am looking if it is possible to run without server.

Comment: No server means that you serve your page with file system, which was a solution I gave you in my answer. Don't try to reinvent the wheel !

Comment: Nowadays the Python option should be `python3 -m http.server <port>`.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: I've just posted a [new answer using relatives links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38786876/1548376). Which is more portable solution.**

I see three solutions to your problem :

### Distribute your code via Github Pages

Use a public or a private repository on [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/) to serve you work.
You can use the ideas developed by [Octopress](http://octopress.org/) to store your code and the generated files on two different branches of your repository and give access to your plain html to developers.

### Configure Jekyll to (nearly) work on file system

By using the `baseurl` configuration variable in `_config.yml`.

If the site's zip is unzipped in `C:/Users/toto/mysite`, add :

```
# No trailing slash
baseurl: "file:///C:/Users/toto/mysite"
```

In default Jekyll templates, assets are called with :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/css/main.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
or
<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/javascripts/script.js"></script>
```

Links and images must make use of `baseurl` to :

```
# html link
<a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>

# markdown link
[{{ page.title }}]({{ site.baseurl }}{{ page.url }})

# html image
<img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/myimage.png">

# markdown image
![Img title]({{ site.baseurl }}/assets/myimage.png)
```

Note : Any page that has a `permalink` set to end with `folder/index.html` 
(eg: `permalink: /about/`) will result in having link targeting `folder/` and land on the folder's files listing page.

### Give a try to an exotic solution for Win users

You can give a try to [Portable Jekyll](https://github.com/madhur/PortableJekyll) that [seems to work on windows](http://eatenbygrues.com/journal/installing-portable-jekyll).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already tried the first 2 solutions that you mentioned & the problem is like i mentioned that i have to send ZIP files to clients or other people involved in the project & base url trick is not very reliable as not everyone uses same OS & also even if they are on same OS then they'll need to extract in specific location.

Comment: Deploy on github or on a private server.

Comment: Thanks for the input but it's not what i am looking for :)